# How to extend the grid in the form?

Tags: magento-1.9, module, admin, grid, forms

I've got the grid in a form but it's in the middle and doesn't take all space forem. How can I do it?

[image: grid1]

```
<?php
class Ns_Thorleif_Block_Adminhtml_Commerciaux_Edit_Form_Renderer_Fieldset_Grid extends Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract{
    protected $_element;

    public function getElementHtml()
    {
        return Mage::helper('core')->getLayout()->createBlock('thorleif/adminhtml_commerciaux_grid')->toHtml();
    }
}
```

**My grid**

[image: grid]

**and how I want to implement it**

[image: how I want to implement it].

Adminhtml/Commerciaux.php

```
class Ns_Thorleif_Block_Adminhtml_Commerciaux extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container
{
 //file del Header
   public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_commerciaux'; // Répertoire où est le block Grid
        $this->_blockGroup = 'thorleif'; // Alias de nos blocks dans config.xml
        $this->_headerText = 'SyncManager';
        // On peut aussi changer le libellé du bouton "Add new" en changeant la propriété _addButtonLabel
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function getHeaderCssClass() {
       return 'icon-head head-customer-groups';
    }

}
```

This is the part form.php

```
// section three
    $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('commerciaux_form_3', array('legend' => 'Category'));
    $fieldset->addType('category_grid', 'Ns_Thorleif_Block_Adminhtml_Commerciaux_Edit_Form_Renderer_Fieldset_Grid');
    $fieldset->addField('category', 'category_grid', array(
        'class' => 'required-entry',
        'required' => true,
        'name' => 'category',
        'onclick' => "",
        'onchange' => "",
        'disabled' => false,
        'readonly' => false,
        'tabindex' => 1,
        'width' => '100%'
    ));
```

Comment: Have you set column width for each grid column?

Comment: no, only for the first one with value 10% and the action column with 100 (only like this). I have to put them? to expand the table to use all form space?

Comment: No. Was just an idea if you had set a fixed width for all ... I'd check CSS if there is something making it not fullscreen. I'v no better idea ATM.

Comment: I understand that there is like "label" column + "value" column in a form for this reason I have it like this but I don't know how some could have the grid using all from space.

Comment: Can you please add full code?

Comment: I've edited my post

Comment: Other code too please ... to try reproduce that.

Comment: I don't know if you will need the renderer php file also? the first one is the grid and the second one is the form where I put the grid.

Comment: current code class must be extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container

Comment: @Vijay-CyberLocker I've edited my post and share the container class and the grid class

Comment: @Vijay-CyberLocker I've put your changes but nothing has been changed in the grid size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've added this CSS code in the Form.php and that resolve my issue

```
<style type="text/css">
    .columns .form-list td.value    { width:auto; padding-right:5px !important; }
    </style>
```

Comment: its apply all used only particular id.

Comment: @Vijay, I didn't get your comment??

Comment: <body class=" modulename-adminhtml-modulename-index" id="html- body">  class name used for only these grid not all because its apply all grid  of magento. please see and apply

Comment: @Vijay where I should put this code? in the form? Should I change something in the Fieldset class or something like this or only add this line at the end of php file Form.php?

Answer (score 0):

Try it code for only first column change

```
$this->addColumn('entity_id',
            array(
                'header' => 'ID',
                'align' => 'right',
                'width' => '50px',
                'index' => 'entity_id'
               )
);
```

Comment: I've tried like you put, also with style => "width:300px" but nothing happens. I've put my grid updated above.

Comment: I still have no solution for my blocker. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've find as edited in my post that the value column equals to 300px by default, so when I put it 100% or uncheck the width the grid looks good expanded. there is a way to add this in the AddField or in the grid form to adjust it please?